# "Of selecting" vs "about selecting"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

What's the correct preposition in this case?

Example sentence:

> He was as nervous of/about selecting a woman as they were of/about being selected.

I searched on Google: "nervous of selecting." Only two results.
I also searched for: "nervous about selecting." 40K results.

So I think "about" is more correct. But I'm not very sure ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only a few adjectives (***scared, afraid*** being two of the most common) referring to a mental state where if the actual cause / target of that state is also present, we almost always link the two using ***of***.

As [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=He%20was%20nervous&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CHe%20was%20nervous%3B%2Cc0) suggests, the sense of ***nervous*** under consideration here has only really become widespread in the past century, but it's worth looking at [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shy%20of%20him&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshy%20of%20him%3B%2Cc0) showing how people have increasingly *shied away from*<sup>1</sup> using the preposition ***of*** with the near-symonymous adjectival usage *I was **shy of** him,* over that same time period.

Usage obviously changes over time, but I'd say the current position is that people would "like" (usually, unconsciously) to standardise on a single preposition to cover as many use cases as possible. And the leading contender here is ***about*** - which is still only gradually replacing ***of*** after ***scared***, and hasn't gained much traction at all after ***afraid***. But it *has* become the most likely choice after ***nervous***, partly because there weren't so many prior instances holding back our natural tendency to move towards standardisation.

In OP's exact context, *nervous **about X*** is definitely already more common than *nervous **of X***, and this preference will only become stronger over time. As of right now, ***of*** is still perfectly acceptable - but if you're looking to the future, you'll be better off getting used to ***about*** right from the start.

---

I'd just like to flag up a fine point regarding the ongoing "transitional" status of ***about*** in relation to ***scared*** (the "new" preposition use hasn't yet had much impact on ***afraid***). Currently, the "standard" form is ***I was scared of him*** - where the "object" is a person, or at least something "tangible".

It's not (yet) very idiomatic to say ***I was scared about him***, but already it's not uncommon to encounter ***I was scared about meeting him*** - where the object is a more "abstract" concept. That's just an example of how newly emerging "standardised" usages gradually gain traction in *specific sub-areas* of the syntactic territory they'll probably eventually colonise completely.

---

<sup>1</sup> ***to shy away from*** = **to avoid**, **to steer clear of**, **to keep away from**

Answer (score 2):

I shall not go so far as to say that "nervous of" is incorrect or that correctness admits of degree. But in terms of modern American usage, "about" is far more common. Indeed, at least in modern American speech, "of" might be deemed affected or might even seem temporarily puzzling.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes adjectives can be used with more than one prepositions and their meanings can change accordingly.

According to [Longman Dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/nervous)

> Being nervous *about something* means being worried.   worried or
>   frightened about something, and unable to relax
>
> Being nervous *of somebody* means being frightened.
>
> We were all a bit nervous of him at first (=frightened of him).